# Swapon --show does not update gb size when resizing disk

Tags: amazon-ec2, swap

I was wondering about something, I used AWS to resize a swap partition on an EC2 instance. When I ssh into the instance and use the command swapon --show in the console I still get the old GB value of the partition, however, if I use lsblk for example, the correct GB value is shown. Is that a bug? Which one of these can I trust now? I want to be certain that the swap space is also properly assigned and used.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to swapoff first and use mkswap and then swapon.

1. sudo swapoff /dev/nvmelnl
2. sudo mkswap /dev/nvmelnl
3. sudo swapon /dev/nvmelnl
4. sudo swpaon --show

Comment: What if I do not do this? Would it mean that the system would not use 15gb but 3gb instead?

Comment: It won't use 15gb.